# Join two Except Clauses into one result set

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is it possible to join two Except Clauses into a single result set ?

This does not work, but it is essentially what I would like to achieve

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.TemptblSHAREVendors EXCEPT SELECT * FROM dbo.tblSHAREVendors
UNION
SELECT * FROM dbo.tblSHAREVendors EXCEPT SELECT * FROM dbo.TemptblSHAREVendors
```

Comment: Reasons not to use images are [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/92546). Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Comment: Aside: If no duplicate rows are expected in the output then `union all` will avoid the overhead of sorting the results to eliminate duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use parenthesis to force the precedence of operations.

```
(SELECT *
        FROM dbo.TemptblSHAREVendors
 EXCEPT
 SELECT *
        FROM dbo.tblSHAREVendors)
UNION
(SELECT *
        FROM dbo.tblSHAREVendors
 EXCEPT
 SELECT *
        FROM dbo.TemptblSHAREVendors);
```